# How can I turn off sending of bitcoins?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, coldstorage, watch-only

I use Bitcoin Core v.0.17 on the server. I want to only be able to receive, and prevent sending. How can I turn off sending of bitcoins through bitcoind, bitcoin-cli or bitcoin.conf?

Comment: What do you mean by "output of bitcoins"?

Comment: Stop send btc, only reciev

Comment: @voodooSHAA: I've edited your post to add this information. Please check whether my edit matches your intentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Stop send btc, only reciev

### Bitcoin Core

So far as I know, there isn't really good support for this in Bitcoin core.

The safest way is to remove your private key(s) from the wallet.

You could archive your existing wallet (and test full recovery carefully) then set up a watch-only wallet using [`importaddress`](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#importaddress)

However note that this does not generate new receiving addresses for you, If you use a new receiving address for each transaction (as you should) than you'll have to generate each address  externally and import it into the watch-only wallet.

Other wallets may have better support for this.

### Offline Wallets

You don't actually need a wallet to receive payments, so long as you don't mind

- the consequent loss of privacy from using a single receiving address.
- the need to trust a third party blockchain explorer to monitor payments received.